# JTable Key Listener

Tags: java, swing, jtable, key-bindings

I need my JTable to validate a given row's data and change column1's component to a JButton, labelled "Save" (ready for record save), if the validation determines that the data is OK. I need to do this in reaction to each keystroke.

No matter how many things I have tried, the user seems to be forced to close the cell editor (by clicking elsewhere or pressing Enter) before the data can be evaluated.

Do you know of a way of having a key listener (or other method) that will provide instant feedback rather than forcing this extra key/mouse stroke?

Data valuation using the DefaultCellEditor still needs this extra keystroke and KeyBindings (which apparently doesn't) seems to need to react to specific keys only.

Is there a way to provide a listener that will react instantly to each keystroke in the editor?

### Follow up from question by m0skit0

Q: What have I tried?

A: I have a class called ButtonColumn, adapted from [Rob Camick](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column) which mplements TableCellRenderer.

This validates the row data and, if validation succeeds it renders the cell as a JButton labelled “Save”, ELSE it returns the theDefaultRendererComponent with the plain text label “New…” (in red font).

I have another class that implements KeyListener which repaint the table every time the user makes a keystroke and thus carries out the SaveButtonRowFormatter validation and rendering (as described above).

This works but only after the cell editor of has been closed. This is the problem: the user must do the work of closing the editor in order for the table to be rendered and the save button to appear. This is not intuitive as there is no obvious reason why the user would make any keystroke after they are sure they have successfully filled in the record. Without any save button at this point they are stuck

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: You mean [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JTextFieldaddKeyListenerKeyListenerl.htm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to provide a listener that will react instantly to each keystroke in the editor?

Add a DocumentListener to the editor component of the editor.

```
DefaultCellEditor dce = (DefaultCellEditor)table.getDefaultEditor(Object.class);
JTextField textField = (JTextField)dce.getComponent();
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(...);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use:

```
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Otherwise, you could do the following:

In your `ActionListener` of your button, you could simply do `if(table.getCellEditor()!=null) table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();`

See this example that first print the model before doing that and then after that.

To try it, simply start editing any cell, then press "Save" (without clicking anywhere else or cancelling the editing state), and you'll see that the output in the console is different (the second output takes into account the last modifications you made).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class TestEditableTable {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestEditableTable.class.getSimpleName());
        Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                row.add("Cell " + i + "," + j);
            }
            data.add(row);
        }
        Vector<String> columns = new Vector<String>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            columns.add("Column " + j);
        }
        final TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
        final JTable table = new JTable(model);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                printDataModel(model);
                if (table.getCellEditor() != null) {
                    table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
                }
                printDataModel(model);
            }

            private void printDataModel(final TableModel model) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                        sb.append(model.getValueAt(i, j)).append(' ');
                    }
                    sb.append("\n");
                }
                System.out.println(sb);
            }
        });
        frame.add(save, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestEditableTable().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```